# Eclipse IDE does not show all items of dialog boxes

Tags: eclipse, ide, visibility, items

When tried to create a new Dynamic Web project in Eclipse Mars, I could not edit/select some items in popped-up window as pictured in the attached file. On some dialog boxes it is even much worse.

As you can see, the display resolution is 1366*768. Any idea how can I fix it?
Thanks.[image]

Comment: Even maximizing dialog windows to full does not solve the problem.

Comment: This may be a solution for Ubuntu users:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/361040/eclipse-menus-are-cut-off-or-dont-show